# Installing and setting the default desktop environment in Debian

Tags: linux, debian, gnome

I recently installed Debian wheezy in my laptop using Debian netinst iso image. I would like to install latest gnome desktop environment but mistakenly downloaded the net installation iso and I also installed it in my system.

So, is there any way to install and **automatically load gnome** without logging in and typing in the command `startx` each time to start the gnome environment? Or, is it better to download and install a live iso?

Answer (score 1):

Usually if you install the `gnome-desktop-environment` and `gdm3` packages, the required dependencies will be installed and the boot loader should autostart:

```
apt-get install gdm3 gnome-desktop-environment
```

But I've got no way to test it right now, so please try that and tell me if it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I connected to the internet through ethernet adapter and installed the desktop environment again using the netinst CD. Thanks for your reply.